# Why the emphasis on typed attributes/methods in MBean definition?

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

From [Oracle's definition of MBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html):

> MBeans are managed beans, Java objects that represent resources to be
>   managed.  An MBean has a management interface consisting of:
>
> 1. Named and typed attributes that can be read and written.
> 2. Named and typed operations that can be invoked
> 3. Typed notifications that can be> emitted by the MBean

Why the emphasis on *typed* in each of the points above? Java is a strongly typed language and all attributes/methods  in a Java class have a type attached to them.  So I am finding this definition confusing. Or am I missing something fundamental here? Are they using typed to mean something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

JMX has more restrictive typing characteristics because often, the types themselves are providing a form of "identity" or signature to the bean attribute or operation. In addition, JMX supports the notion of [Open Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/package-summary.html) where a complex type is broken down into its primitive definitions so it can be represented externally to the JVM (perhaps in JConsole where that specific class might not be in the classpath.)

Don't get hung up on it though... all it means is that an MBean's Attributes are defined by their name, and their type. No surprise there really :)